# Apollo React - `useMutation` in ApolloClient setup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, apollo

I have an interesting situation.

I want to initiate refresh token request USING Apollo itself (a.k.a to call a mutation)

Any idea, how to achieve something like this?

```
export default new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
      // useMutation(REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN)
    }),
  ]),

  new HttpLink({...}),
})
```

Basically I'm just trying to `useMutation(REFRESH_ACCESS_TOKEN)` inside `onError` while creating new ApolloClient instance.

The problem:
`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Thanks.

Comment: Well the main problem here is that instead of getting the access token using let's say `axios` I would like to fetch it using graphql's mutation. As the backend itself provides the refresh as a mutation. 

Or in other words the main problem is that I'm trying to use React Hooks in the Class initialization basically.

Comment: you're probably looking for something like https://github.com/sysgears/apollo-universal-starter-kit/blob/1b78ab94697e3beaae4256dfd6a89f5e78e73955/modules/user/client-react/access/jwt/index.jsx#L82

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a hook outside a functional React component. You can use the client directly to make queries and mutations -- just bear in mind that any queries ran this way will not be observable (i.e. won't be updated if the cache changes).

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
      client.mutate({ mutation, variables })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }),
    new HttpLink({...}),
  ]),
})

export default client
```

Comment: I think this could be a solution. I would just also wrap up that `client.mutate` part into the Apollo’s `return new Observable(observer => {...})`